# Set default skin tone for all Emojis in Emoji keyboard in iOS 11?

Tags: ios, input-source, emoji

It appears that it is only possible to change each Emoji’s skin tone individually by tapping and holding on the Emoji key and selecting another skin tone in the pop-up menu.

Is it possible to set a default skin tone to be used across all the supported Emojis?

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by global reset? Are you looking for a way to set a particular skin tone for all supported Emojis?

Comment: @NimeshNeema Yes. And whenever new emojis are added to Unicode, they shall by default appear in my desired default skin tone.

Comment: If possible, I would also like to know how to do the same in mac os.

Answer (score 4):

No. Due to the way it is implemented, it is not possible to set a default skin tone to be used across all the supported Emojis in iOS Emoji keyboard.

Each Emoji remembers its last used skin tone. Also, the recently used section shows all the skin tones variations used for a single Emoji.

[image] [image]

Comment: “Each Emoji remembers its last used skin tone”—it does not for me.

Comment: I too thought that there would be a way so I googled it and landed here. I just bought an iphone after many years as a happy Android user, and it's incredible how little customization iOS offers... is this the price one pays for beautiful looking designs?

Answer (score 0):

Tap the emoji, push up to the skin tones without taking your finger off the screen, then push your finger up again. Try it:)
I apologize if it doesn’t work, a friend taught me.