# Why does Apple continually ask my preferred emoji skin tone?

Tags: macos, ios, emoji

I have never in my life ever chosen any alternate skin tone for emojis beyond the default yellow. But for unknown reasons, Apple asks anew seemingly every month on macOS and iOS if I wouldn’t rather use some non-yellow color for hands and faces. Is there no way to stop this time-wasting and thought-disrupting annoyance? Thank you.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/343670/489896

Comment: I am not long-pressing in iOS nor in macOS.